# removing array elements containing the certain specified and placing them at last

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array generated by a system (downloaded). The order is always random.

I need to remove certain items and place them at last

download_array1 = ["me","father","mother","sister","you","brother","grandfather","grandmother"]
download_array2 = ["brother","grandfather","me","grandmother","father","mother","sister","you"]
download_array3 = ["you","father","mother","grandmother","sister","me","brother","grandfather",""]

input_always_place_at_last = ["me","you"]

expected output

```
["father","mother","sister","brother","grandfather","grandmother","me","you"]
["brother","grandfather","grandmother","father","mother","sister","me","you"]
["father","mother","grandmother","sister","brother","grandfather","me","you"]
```

I have tried with

```
download_array1.includes(input_always_place_at_last).push(input_always_place_at_last)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different approaches to doing this. The most basic is to check the index of the item and splice the array to remove it and push it to end of array

```js
download_array1 = ["me","father","mother","sister","you","brother","grandfather","grandmother"] 

input_always_place_at_last = ["me","you"]

for(let item of input_always_place_at_last){
  const idx = download_array1.indexOf(item);
  if(idx > -1){
    download_array1.splice(idx,1);
    download_array1.push(item)
  }
}

console.log(download_array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the unique, but you can implement this using `Array.reduce` as below.

The variable `input_always_place_at_last` as name implies expected to be placed always at the end can be concatenated with the result of reduce function.

```js
download_array1 = ["me", "father", "mother", "sister", "you", "brother", "grandfather", "grandmother"];
download_array2 = ["brother", "grandfather", "me", "grandmother", "father", "mother", "sister", "you"];
download_array3 = ["you", "father", "mother", "grandmother", "sister", "me", "brother", "grandfather", ""];
input_always_place_at_last = ["me", "you"];

function updateArray (arr, lastItems) {
  const op = arr.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    if (lastItems.indexOf(curr) === - 1 && curr.length > 0) {
      acc.push(curr);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
  const output = op.concat(lastItems);
  return output;
}

conole.log(updateArray(download_array1, input_always_place_at_last));
conole.log(updateArray(download_array2, input_always_place_at_last));
conole.log(updateArray(download_array3, input_always_place_at_last));
```